# Wordpress, trying to install essential plugins. but got freeze page

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress on ubuntu vps, after installing the theme, some others essential plugins needs to be installed. After clicking on  install I got freeze page and no advancement.

[image]

Comment: What’s in the wordpress error logs?

Comment: @Klaassiek, I'm beginner in wordpress, it was because the theme and their plugins are old. So I changed the theme